How to Remesh faces/dissolve edges based on mesh island area/or face surface area in geometry nodes?
I want to "procedurally re-mesh" a mesh based on how big I want each new face to be. For example, I have a grid with a total surface area of 580 square feet (it would be nice to find a node tree that tells me the exact surface area of the total mesh). I want to recursively re-mesh those 580 square feet (I say recursively because recursive subdivision can give a variety of shapes and sizes from large squares to medium rectangles similar to what I want, but I don't think I can use that since I want to make the grid faces bigger, so recursive decimation makes more sense) so each new face have a surface area ranging from 50 square feet to 150 square feet. The original mesh was a grid (before some faces were deleted), so I am not working with a dense or "difficult-to-re-mesh" mesh, that is if it was manual and non-procedural. The problem is doing it in geometry nodes, as you can see from the screenshots, I have 2 different generated meshes from different seeds (which is why I can't do it manually, as that would break once I change the seed). The blue lines I drew show how I would like them to be re-meshed. The one with the blue diagonal dashes is the one I would like to have an exception for (like any group of random faces where one of their edges is facing the -y direction will be re-meshed to 1 face with a smaller surface area of 28 square feet, instead of the bigger ones like the rest). Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.




